# ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo coger un valor de una página web externa? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera usando javascript:

```
var myWindow = window.open("https://www.eltiempo.es/"+part2+".html","Nuevo Explorador","width=300,height=300,scrollbars=NO");

var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('m_table_weather_day_max_temp');
console.log(testElements);
```

Pero sale todo el rato `undefined`, ¿qué puedo hacer?

Comment: El motivo por el que te escribe undefined es porque los elementos los estas buscando en document (página actual) no en la ventana que estás abriendo con window.open. Como no los encuentra en la página actual, devuelve undefined.

Comment: A parte del buen apunte que te hace @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA, solo podrás acceder, a través de javascript, al DOM de una ventana abierta si se cumplen las [políticas de mismo origen (ver documentación)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_politica). Si es una página externa el contenido estará protegido por el navegador.

Comment: ¿Y qué podrían hacer? he probado poniendo el myWindow delante y aun así no me va, me sale un html collection, pero sin mostrar el valor que necesito.

Comment: @CapThencapthen Como te han dicho, un navegador no puede (o no deberia) dejarte hacer lo que estás tratando de hacer. Hay varias formas en las que puedes solventarlo. Idealmente, deberías intentar comunicarte mediante AJAX con la API que tuviera el sitio para hacer las consultas. Si eso no fuese posible, otra forma sería hacer que desde tu backend se haga una petición GET (mediante CURL por ejemplo) a la url del tiempo, y la respuesta parseada la renderice en tu frontend. De esa manera tendrías acceso a esos elementos en document para hacer lo que necesites con JavaScript..

Comment: No me gusta usar mucho iframe..., pero puede iframe en este caso saltarse los origines cruzados???? de todas maneras no es una solucion que me agrade ni de cerca, es mas solo deberia tomarse en cuenta la respuesta a mi pregunta como una curiosidad mas bien.